# Are user defined functions callable?

Tags: python, numpy

I am not a very experience programmer. Please can you tell me why this code gives me the error message:

error: quad: first argument is not callable

code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as integrate

def parabola(x, a):
    return a+x**2

x=np.arange(-10, 10, 1)

plt.plot(x, parabola(x,2))

plt.show()

int1=integrate.quad(parabola(x,2), -5, 5)
print int1
```

Should all user defined functions be callable?

Comment: You shouldn't be calling the function. Functions are callable, pass `parabola` without those parameters

Comment: or `lambda x : parabola(x,2)`

Comment: _Functions_ are callable. Function _return values_ may be, but usually they are not.

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems in your code:

1) you call the function `parabola()`. Instead, pass it as an argument to `integrate`.

2) `parabola()` is a two argument function. `integrate` expects a single-argument function.

To solve the second problem, you need to convert the two-argument function to a single-argument function. This is a general technique known as *partial application* of functions.

Try this:

```
def parabola1(x): return parabola(x, 2)

int1 = integrate.quad(parabola1, -5, 5)
print int1
```

Comment: Or `integrate.quad(functools.partial(a=2), -5 , 5)` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.partial)).

Comment: @CristianCiupitu typo? `integrate.quad(functools.partial(parabola, a=2), -5 , 5)`

Comment: Or `integrate.quad(lambda x: parabola(x, 2), -5, 5)`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
int1=integrate.quad(parabola, -5, 5, args=(2,))
```

The `quad` signature is:

```
quad(func, a, b, args=(), ...)
```

the function, lower range, upper range, args_to_pass through, etc.